Jetty 12 Hot Deploy Issue
I have recently upgraded a Jetty 11 server to Jetty 12. We did this by installing a new Jetty 12 instance and moving apps across as needed.
Prior to Jetty 11, we were using Jetty 9. In all cases we have used the same setup, keeping a war file in the /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/webapps folder and deploying to Jetty using an xml file in /opt/jetty/my_base/webapps
The applications that we are deploying are Spring Boot 3.0 apps built using Java 17.
With a similar setup on previous versions of Jetty, we have used the hot deploy functionality to redeploy the application once the xml file is updated. However, on Jetty 12, this is not working.
With Jetty 12, things are slightly different there are multiple deploy options/environments, but we are only using the ee10 deploy module. I have updated /etc/ee10-deploy.xml to include a scan interval as follows:
<Set name="scanInterval"><Property name="jetty.deploy.scanInterval" default="1"/>1</Set>

However, the application does not deploy when the xml is updated. At the moment the only way to force the deploy is to restart the server. When the xml is updated, I can see in Jetty's log's that it is taking all of the usual steps to deploy the application with no obvious error, yet the application remains unchanged in browser.
Here is an example of the xml that we are using for deployment:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/@app@</Set>
    <Set name="war">/var/www/vhosts/@fileLocation@/webapps/@app@.war</Set>
    <Set name="virtualHosts">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>@domain@</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>    
</Configure>

I have read elsewhere that a properties file can be used to set the environment, but this has not helped. In our case there is only one environment and as per Jetty documentation, the properties file is only needed if there are multiple environments.
Is there anything else that I need to do to configure hot deployment on Jetty 12?
